# Codeigniter helper function to validation rules

Tags: php, forms, validation, function, codeigniter

I created a helper for checking if a user id exists in my `user` database table:

```
   if ( ! function_exists('valid_user'))
    {
        function valid_user($user_id)
        {
            $ci=& get_instance();
            $ci->load->database(); 

            $ci->db->select('id');
            $ci->db->where('id', $user_id);
            $ci->db->where('activated', 1);
            $ci->db->where('banned', 0);
            $ci->db->limit(1);
            $query = $ci->db->get('users');

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) //if user exists
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

I added the function to my validation rule like so

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[11]|is_natural_no_zero|valid_user');
```

It does not perform the `valid_user` function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try adding the `valid_user` function to the controller where form_validation is run?

Comment: Also it seems that, in your `set_rules`, you have to set `callback_valid_user` not `valid_user` according to the http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: @user: Both of your comments will go towards solving the problem; add them as answers, not as comments!

Comment: duuuuuuuuuuuuude don't wrap your function declaration in an if statement. that's not good practice.

Comment: @FinalForm, why not? Do you mean `if ( ! function_exists('valid_user'))` ? Codeigniter helper functions are wrapped like that too.

Comment: @CyberJunkie no, that's wrapping a function call in an if conditional test, between (), which is ok. Wrapping a function call in an if statement is also OK, between {}. Wrapping a function **declaration** in an if statement is not good practice. It's where you declare your function code inside an if statement. e.g. `if(something) {function (){ some function code }}`

Comment: @FinalForm, sorry I still don't understand what I did wrong. Do you mean `num_rows()` in the if statement?

Comment: @CyberJunkie You declared `valid_user` within a if statement. This is not a good practice, because duplicate function names may lead to unpredicted (one of random 2) behaviors.

Comment: @user482594, I must be an idiot, I still don't get it. lol. In the first statement - `if (!function_exists('valid_user'))` I'm making sure the function does not exist to AVOID duplicate function names.. if that's what is being referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous experience, I usually added a validation function (in your case, `valid_user`) in the same place where the callback is called.

For example, I would put `valid_user` method in a users_controller where one of the registration methods will invoke the `valid_user` method.

Also, it seems that, in your `set_rules`, you have to set `callback_valid_user` not `valid_user` according to the Codeigniter user guides.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: It seems that I have to return the helper function within a function in the controller, then use that function as callback in the validation. Some other helpers of mine work in the validation rules without using `callback_` . I just add the function name directly. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID',
'required|xss_clean|max_length[11]|is_natural_no_zero|callback_valid_user');
//note the callback_                                     ↑
```

Comment: It's not a callback within the controller, I have the function in a helper file.